# Wireshark show http only three wave not four data transition

Tags: http, wireshark

[image]

When I'm a Student, being taught there is 4 process in stop http connection.
However today I test only 3 process. It's Wireshark merge data transition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were likely taught that TCP connections require a four way close:  FIN/ACK -> ACK, FIN/ACK -> ACK.  This is true, but it does not have to take four packets to do it.

In the case that you present, the 192.168.0.106 host begins to close with a FIN/ACK.  The other end of the connection, rather than simply ACKing this, takes the opportunity to begin closing as well.  So, when it responds with a FIN/ACK, it is both ACKing the FIN that it received and beginning its own close.  The final packet is the acknowledgement of the FIN from the 211 host.

What this means is that, in this case, only three packets were used, but we still had a FIN from host A that was acknowledged and a FIN from host B that was acknowledged.  That is really the only requirement in the protocol.

Comment: Why we say http 3 shake hand not 4, in establing http connection?

Comment: I'm sorry for my poor expression.I mean Why we always say "Threre is 3 step in establishing http connection.4 step in distconnecting http connection." As I known, FIN is just a flag, won't enlarge http datagram. Why we not say 3 step in disconnecting http connection ?

Comment: Because that is what the TCP RFC specifies.